# I can't reach into the verify callback when using passportjs's new OAuthStrategy() for twitter's 3-legged-auth

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, oauth-1.0a

I would like to use Oauth1.o to get credentials from a provider but I am halfway stuck. I am using [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/oauth/) for the implementation.

Here is the brief code:

1. `oauth.js`

```
    const passport = require('passport');
    const OAuthStrategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuthStrategy;

    passport.use(
        'provider',
        new OAuthStrategy({
            requestTokenURL: "****",
            accessTokenURL: "****",
            userAuthorizationURL: "****",
            consumerKey: "****",
            consumerSecret: "****",
            callbackURL: "****",
        },
        (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
            store[token] = tokenSecret;
            console.log(profile);
            done(null, profile);
        })
    );

    module.exports = passport;
```

2. Express mini-app(modularised routing)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const passport = require('./oauth');

/**
 * Initialize Passport
 * Restore authentication state, if any, from the session
 */
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());

router.get('/oauth/sign-in', passport.authenticate('provider'));

router.get('/oauth/callback', (req, res) => {
    const { oauth_token, oauth_verifier, denied } = req.query;

    if (denied !== null && denied !== undefined) {
        req.session.destroy();
        res.json(denied);
    }

    res.json({ oauth_token, oauth_verifier });
});

module.exports = router;
```

From the above code, I successfully get to the callback URL after I authorize the app on the Twitter page. But I am unable to console.log the token, tokenSecret & profile. The documentation was also not clear to me as to how to use the `done` callback function.

I am on a learning journey using https://github.com/twitterdev/twauth-web/blob/master/twauth-web.py and would rather avoid using passport-twitter to learn master the example they have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the authenticate middleware in the callback route as well. You can check out the docs [here](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/oauth/):

```
router.get('/oauth/callback', passport.authenticate('provider', {
  failureRedirect: '/login' //optional
}),
  (req, res) => {
    //...your code...
  });
```

Comment: Hmm..thanks man. I will try this out at a later time and confirm the results. Neat profile picture.

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to see the token & tokenSecret on my logs